# How to find which XML file contains the missing element?

Tags: python, xml, deep-learning, nlp, elementtree

Newbie in Python and Deep Learning here!

I have 10,000 XML files that contain information about patent documents (obtained from WIPO). I want to extract the titles, abstracts and classifications of each document. I have managed to do so using ElementTree and saved them in 3 lists, but I realized that there is one document that is missing the classification element, how do I find out which one is it?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
abstracts=[]
titles=[]
tags=[]

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if not filename.endswith('.xml'): continue
    file = os.path.join(path, filename)
    tree = ET.parse(file)
    root = tree.getroot()

    for title in root.iter('invention-title'):
        titles.append(child.text)

    for abs in root.iter('abstract'):
        abstracts.append(abs.text)

    for tag in root.findall('ipc-postreform'):
        tags.append(tag.find('classification-ipc').text)
```

```
len(abstracts)
10000

len(titles)
10000

len(tags)
9999
```

Thank you!!

Comment: So you have 10,000 xml files in your directory and each one has one title, one abstract and (usually) one "ipc-postreform" element?

Comment: yes that's right

Comment: Just compare the lengths of abstracts, titles, tags at the end of each iteration and you'll find the one missing. Each XML contains one of each, why are you using a for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood your code and use case correctly, you can check for a title, abstract and classification as you go.

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

abstracts=[]
titles=[]
tags=[]

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if not filename.endswith('.xml'): continue
    file = os.path.join(path, filename)
    tree = ET.parse(file)
    root = tree.getroot()

    title = next(root.iter('invention-title'))
    # title = root.find('invention-title')

    abstract = next(root.iter('abstract'))
    # abstract = root.find('abstract')

    tag = next(root.findall('ipc-postreform'))

    if not tag:
        raise Exception('Tag not found for {}'.format(title))

    classification = tag.find('classification-ipc').text

    if not classification:
        raise Exception('Classification not found for {}'.format(title))

    titles.append(title)
    tags.append(classification)
    abstracts.append(abstract)
```

As @Mihail Burduja mentions, there's no need for a for loop so I have replaced them with one call to `next()`.  You can probably use `find()` instead.